# Managing pages in TVJS

Tags: javascript, tvos

I am trying to follow this article where he describes baby steps on using

In this section, he tried to describe how to jump from a page to another. I am trying to see if I can do 4-levels, but couldn't know how; It might be a pure JS question as well.

```
> App.onLaunch = function(options) {
>     alert("Hello!", function() {
>       var helloDocument = getDocumentContents("http://localhost:8000/hello.tvml", function(xhr)
> {
>         navigationDocument.dismissModal();
>         navigationDocument.pushDocument(xhr.responseXML);
>       });
>     }); }
```

Is there anyone to help, how to do callback ?

```
> App.onLaunch = function(options) {
>     alert("Hello!", function() {
>       var helloDocument = getDocumentContents("http://localhost:8000/hello.tvml", function(xhr)
> {
>         navigationDocument.dismissModal();
>         navigationDocument.pushDocument(xhr.responseXML);
>       });
>     }); }
```

Comment: alert is a previous defined function in this code, it's not an standard 'alert' call. That's why it's handling the callback.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to other pages, you need to push these pages on the stack:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var newPageDocument = parser.parseFromString(NEW_PAGE_XML, 'application/xml');
navigationDocument.pushDocument(newPageDocument);
```

To return to the previous page, you can press the Menu button on the remote or call the popDocument method of navigationDocument:

```
navigationDocumemt.popDocument();
```

Here's how your code will look, assuming that getDocumentContents is a method that fetches the XML from hello.tvml:

```
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
  getDocumentContents("http://localhost:8000/hello.tvml", function(response) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var firstDocument = parser.parseFromString(response, 'application/xml');
    navigationDocument.pushDocument(firstDocument);
  });
}
```

Also, alert isn't supported, but console is.